# Where Linux places the messages of boot?

Tags: linux, boot, centos, logging

I want to find place to where Linux writes all boot messages. You know:

```
facility one    [STARTED]
facility two    [STARTED]
facility three  [FAILED]
```

I searched with

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "words from boot messages"
```

in /var/log/, but found nothing.

I have CentOS 5.5.
For example at boot time I had: "Determining IP information for eth0... failed; no link present. Check cable?"
I don't care about error specificaly, but I can't find any log that holds this error.

`dmesg | grep "no link present"` returns nothing too.

Comment: did you run the `find` command with root permissions? `find` will print all files you can list, but `grep` can only check the files you can read & some log files might be owned by root withput read permissions for other users. Also, at least GNU grep supports th `-l` option to print the names of files with matches instead of matched lines. This can be very usefule looking for files that contain certain text. So try `su -c 'find /var/log -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -i "words from boot messages"'` or `sudo find /varlog -print0 | xargs -0 sudo grep -l -i "words from boot messages"`

Comment: Nowadays with systemd [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345978/209677) is the answer.

Answer (score 28):

Most of the boot messages are put in a buffer, that you can access using the command `dmesg`. On most Linux distributions, that output is also stored in

```
/var/log/dmesg.log
```

That you can view with

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/dmesg.log
```

Comment: For example, I had at boot time: "Determining IP information for eth0... failed; no link present Check cable?" I don't care about this error specificaly, but when I do: dmesg | grep "no link present" I get nothing... Actually I get VERY MUCH lines with grep "eth0", but not with concrete error. So is there way to find concrete boot errors description or no? (Thank you for reply to the point)

Comment: Try using `Nano`'s ^w (whereis) command, essentially a Find command. Or `grep` with a relaxed regexp. If you are really worried about a specific command's output, you could go in it's `init.d` file and change the offending command's STDOUT or STDERR logging.

Comment: No `/var/log/dmesg.log` on Lubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 20):

Every exceptional entry during boot is placed in `/var/log/syslog` Could also be in `/var/log/boot.msg`

Comment: I have CentOS 5.5 and I have no syslog in /var/log/

Comment: boot.log (generally boot.log(x) where x is positive integer or nothing) is empty.

Comment: Try /var/log/messages

Comment: /var/log/boot.msg  is the correct one on linux mint

Comment: may also contain non-exceptional entries.

Answer (score 9):

This solution surely works on Debian systems, but maybe can be useful anyway.

In order to store **all** the messages shown during the boot you have to start a service called `bootlogd`, after the next reboot you can read the messages in `/var/log/boot`.

Comment: On debian wheezy, I get `root@wheezy:/home/jrx# service bootlogd start
bootlogd: unrecognized service`

Comment: @JérômeRadix maybe you should install it first?

Answer (score 3):

Type 
dmesg > ~/dmesg.log
to copy all the boot messages into your own copy.
You can add the date and time if you want to keep multiple copies
and you could even automate it within a login script.